# Why am I receiving "check if the declared type is right and if the method exists" when retrieving page properties for sling?

Tags: java, sling

This code snippet is supposed to get the page properties in sling.

Why am I receiving this error: `Please check if the declared type is right
and if the method exists.`

```
private String properties;

public void setProperties(String properties){
    this.properties = property;       
    ValueMap property = (ValueMap) properties.getAttribute("properties");
    pageTitle = property.get("pageTitle", "");
}
```

Comment: This code is kind of a mess, and the edits people have been making aren't helping. It won't compile as-is, so perhaps you could show us the code you're *actually* using, and what the actual error you're getting is.

Comment: sorry @EdwardFalk made some revisions.

Comment: It's still wrong. Does this even compile? You're declaring **property** *after* you first use it. And as Jigar has pointed out, class String doesn't have a **getAttribute()** method.  Who is calling **setProperties()** and where is the argument coming from? I think the error message means exactly what it says: You need to check to see if "String" is the right declaration for "properties".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`properties` is of type `String` which doesn't have the methods you are trying to access

Comment: thanks for replying @Jigar, so then I'm really confused how do you access the methods I'm trying to use?

Comment: from where you got the reference of those methods, may be check java doc of the library you are using and change the tpe

Comment: thanks @Jigar properties is a "ValueMap" that I needed to pass in not a string. good call!